# AT power connector wiring?

Tags: motherboard, power-supply, connector

Ok, I have an old Compaq Presario Socket 7 motherboard from a ~5000 series Presario. A long time ago I let my brother borrow the power supply, and he tossed it claiming it "didn't work". Of course, I didn't realize at the time that it was wired differently than any other power supply I seem to be able to find. It takes 3 of these slot-shaped 6-pin connectors, I can find a few on newark's website, though I might like a confirmation on which exact connector it is. (I can't find a picture right now, but I know that some, but not all ATX PSUs have maybe one of them). Usually they're labelled on a power supply as "P6" or "P7".

So, I'd like to know the specific connector name, but I think I can find it regardless (I don't have a picture on hand), and more importantly, I need to know how to wire it up. Actually, I found a website in posting this and they are *AT* style power connectors, the two main ones are P8 and P9, but I still need to know what the third same-style connector is and how to wire them all properly.

http://img825.imageshack.us/img825/8599/imag0065d.jpg http://img52.imageshack.us/img52/8308/imag0066gs.jpg

And a link to the site with somewhat relevant information: http://www.pcguide.com/ref/power/sup/partsMotherboard-c.html

If I wire the third one as the auxillary 6-pin connector, I could just as well wire it backwards since the connector only goes on one way, but the picture has no visual aids to tell me which side is which.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

These are the original PC main power connectors. You can see a perfect match, with full specs, on [this page](http://www.playtool.com/pages/psuconnectors/connectors.html#oldpc). Pin one is on the far right -- you can tell by looking at the wiring colors in the picture with the connectors attached.

Comment: Awesome, that gives me everything I needed to know.